# C# Entity Framework how to dynamically add 'And' , 'or' condition to the query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have following method which applies AND condition. But I would like to have OR condition based on parameter in filter.

```
public async Task<IList<PerformanceReportUser>> GetUsersForPerformanceReport(PerformanceReportFilter filter)
{
    var query = _context.Set<EntityUser>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsQueryable();

    if(filter != null)
    {
        if (filter.Modified.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.Modified >= filter.Modified);
        }

        // How can I have dynamically the OR condition based on filter parameter?

        if (filter.Created.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.Created >= filter.Created);
        }
    }

    var result = query.Select(user => ToDomain(user));

    return await result.ToListAsync();
}
```

Basically in SQL, I am expecting something like below.

If parameter is 'Or':

```
Select * 
From EntityUser
Where Created >= '2021-01-01' Or Modified >= '2022-02-02'
```

If parameter is 'And'

```
Select * 
From EntityUser
Where Created >= '2021-01-01' And Modified >= '2022-02-02'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `OR` inside this types of querys, you have to do in same line, something similar to this:

```
var query = _context.Set<EntityUser>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsQueryable();
        
    if(filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(q => 
            (filter.Modified.HasValue && q.Modified >= filter.Modified)
            ||
            (filter.Created.HasValue && q.Created >= filter.Created)
        );      
    }
```

### EDITED

If you want dinamicaly condition based on filter use something similar to this...

```
var query = _context.Set<EntityUser>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsQueryable();

    if(filter != null)
    {
        if(filter.condition == "OR"){
            query = query.Where(q => 
                (filter.Modified.HasValue && q.Modified >= filter.Modified)
                ||
                (filter.Created.HasValue && q.Created >= filter.Created)
            ); 
            
        }else{
            
            query = query.Where(q => 
                (filter.Modified.HasValue && q.Modified >= filter.Modified)
                &&
                (filter.Created.HasValue && q.Created >= filter.Created)
            ); 
        }
             
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am expecting something different. Have updated t he question with expecting sql query

Comment: This code solves your problem with small modification^^

Comment: But what if i want to have && operator based on a condition?

Comment: your solution will always use OR right

Comment: @MukilDeepthi put and if... if operator = &&, exec and query, else, exec or query... query is the same as described, you have only to change || with &&

Comment: Answer edited...

Comment: I guess, what's missing is that you'd need to include that info ("OR" or "AND") in your filter parameter. This method cannot autmagically know if you want those with AND or OR.